# Access Unit test case report of other projects

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, nunit, specflow

I need to create a dashboard application which will show all Unit test coverage report of projects, there are many projects which are deployed in various server. all are visual studio 2010 and 2012 projects with NUnit.

Please suggest me some idea or sample.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to access the reports that are automatically generated from your continuous build system. e.g. TeamCity provides detailed reports for each build and also trend analysis over time for each project if you add coverage to the unit test run.

http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/#Quality_Tracking

Otherwise you are looking at doing it the hard way. Run the unit test with your process monitored by coverage tool, record the data, then build a dashboard to show all the combined data.